# cargo-maven2-plugin execution start container failed

Tags: java, maven, glassfish-4, cargo, cargo-maven2-plugin

I am trying to configure the `cargo-maven2-plugin` to start my local install of Glassfish 4.1. I have the following configured in my pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.14</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-container</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-container</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>glassfish4x</containerId>
                    <home>${glassfish.installDirectory}</home>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <type>existing</type>
                </configuration>
                <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <pingURL>${web.app.url}</pingURL>
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But it fails with the following

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.14:start (start-container)
>   on project UsersJSFMavenApplication: Execution start-container of goal
>   org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.14:start failed: Cannot
>   create configuration. There's no registered configuration for the
>   parameters (container [id = [glassfish4x], type = [installed]],
>   configuration type [existing]). Actually there are no valid types
>   registered for this configuration. Maybe you've made a mistake
>   spelling it? -> [Help 1]

Any ideas?